# Real time notification in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a PHP application, where I want one user make a database entry. It should be reflected to all the users whoever have this app open on their browser will get instant notification that some data has been updated on the database or with whatever data has been inserted.

Is there any way I can get real time notification of data inserted or updated? On all the opened browser without any delay.

We use AJAX for now. But it seems like our application is now working slow due to continues request. Any other way? Which is free.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at socket.io? It's, like it sounds, a web sockets-based technology for real-time communication between server and browser: http://socket.io/

Comment: @HannesJohansson socket.io is a Node.js library – not a PHP one. You don't need JS on the server side to use web sockets. It seems to be fashionable these days to tell everyone “Don't use the programming language you are used to – switch to JavaScript for everything and do it now.” This is stupid nonsense.

Comment: Hello, Socket.io is good. But it needs node.js and i have a shared server. How can i implement this one shared server. Can i do that?

Comment: @user3201500 You can't. Use PHP as before…

Comment: Why socket.io? Why not just [PHP Sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Post that as an alternative answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets). One existing library example for PHP is [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

Comment: Can i use this for real time notifications? And will it work on shared hosting too?

Comment: Yes and Yes. It is a normal PHP library to be deployed with your code.

Comment: Ratchet and web sockets both are same?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Pusher (https://pusher.com/). It does what you want to achieve and it works like a charm.

I don't know what do you use on your server side but even if it isn't Laravel, take a look at Jeffrey's Laracast about implementing real time notifications in Laravel (PHP). https://laracasts.com/lessons/pusher-awesomeness

Have a fun! When I did it, my app became extremely sexy. Real time notifications, DOM manipulations etc.

Comment: I am using codeignitor. And for pusher i guess there is some pricing on it.

Comment: CI is fine. In terms of price - start with sandbox. It's free Pusher playground! **You pay nothing** and you can implement everything you need. :) Really give it a try.

Comment: @slick .. Can we go live with Pusher sandbox account ?